# Simple JNDI not working with Parallels VM

Tags: pentaho, kettle

We use JNDI connections for all of our jobs.

I recently upgraded to a new Macbook pro and now, none of my jobs/transformations using JNDI work. All fail with a "No suitable driver found" error.

This is really weird since the /lib subdirectory has the necessary JAR files. I put them there. I made sure my jdbc.properties file is correctly located in /Volumes/C/data-integration-5.3/simple-jndi.

Even after I copied the simple-jndi directory to /Volumes/C/ and to /Volumes/C/.pentaho, the problem remains. "No suitable driver found" error.

The problem exists with multiple JDBC drivers (Oracle, MySQL and Postgres), not just one. Where should the simple-jndi directory be located???

My laptop runs OS X Yosemite with Parallels software for MS Windows 7 pro emulation.

Comment: Have you tried this: http://infocenter.pentaho.com/help48/index.jsp?topic=%2Fpdi_user_guide%2Fconcept_pdi_usr_working_with_jndi_carte.html

Comment: yes, I have. Same results.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have ojdbc7.jar accessible.

Comment: It is. So are the other JAR files. I have chmod-ed all of the files as +rwx, for the heck of it. Same error.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.

My VM user id was not a domain user id . Only local. After my helpdesk guy fixed it, I am now able to use JNDI without problem.

Weird but it works.